# Converting invalid values upon BULK INSERT in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I've got a data set of individuals and their corresponding ages. If an age is unknown, it is marked as'?'. Looks something like this:
Individual|Age
   person1|?
   person2|8
I've then got a table in SQL with a VARCHAR column for 'Individual', and a INT column for 'Age'. Obviously when I run a BULK INSERT:

```
WITH (
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
);
```

And get errors when '?' (char) values try to be inserted into the INT column.

What I was wondering is if there was a way to upon encountering an invalid value, to instead just insert a NULL value?

Comment: Load into a staging table where all the columns are strings.  Then do the data transformations in the database.  It is usually much simpler to do that.

Answer (score 0):

if you prefer to do the sanitize the data on the code, you could look up to "mutator".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you capture the data you need to insert, but you may utilize Case When statement and do something like this:

```
declare @age varchar(10) 
set @age ='?'
insert into [dbo].[IndTbl]([Individual],[Age])
select 'person1', case @age when '?' then Null else @age end
```